# Why Arrays.copyOf so slow?

Tags: java

The function `ArrayList.add()` works very fast. I checked the source code, and saw the implement was `Arrays.copyOf()`

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

But when I use the method `Arrays.copyOf()` in my code, it becomes very slow. You can just run the code below to see it:

```
public class TestArrayCopy {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      list.add(i, i);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);

    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Integer[] array = new Integer[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length +1);
      array[i] = i;
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because it doesn't always happen when `grow` is called?

Comment: You should read source code more carefully so you will notice that `Arrays.copyOf` don't occur every time the `add` method is called.

Comment: Thanks, I should read more carefully!

Comment: BTW see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is calling `copyOf()` *every* time a new element is added:

- The first time, no elements need copying because the original array's length is 0.
- The second time, one element must be copied.
- The third time, two elements.
- The fourth time, three elements.
- ...and so on.

So for every element that is added, you must du more and more work to copy the previous elements. So if you are adding `n` elements, you'll have to perform a total of `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1) = n * (n - 1) / 2 = n^2 / 2 - n / 2` copyings of individual elements. So your runtime is porportional to the *square* of the number of elements you add.

Contrast this with the proper approach, which is to have a larger array than you need (which gives you headroom to add more elements without copying all the time), and to *multiply* the size by a fixed factor every time you need to expand. This requires that you separately keep track of how many elements you've added and lie to your users about your true size. The factor is usually less than 2 (the Java code uses 1.5: `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);`), but the math is simpler if we use 2:

- The initial array size is some small but nonzero number, e.g. 4, so you can add 4 elements for free (well, for the cost of allocating and initializing the array, which in practice will be 4)
- For the fifth element, double the size to 8 and copy the 4 old elements; you can now add 4 more
- For the ninth element, double the size to 16 and copy the 8 old elements; you can now add 8 more
- And so on: for the *n + 1* th element, you double the size to *2 * n* and copy the old *n* elements, which gives you space for *n* more elements.

Even without evaluating the sum of the copyings, we can see that every batch of *n* new elements has already been "paid for" by the copying of the previous *n* elements, so the copying work is *linear* instead of quadratic. And indeed, `4 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + n / 2 + n = 2 * n` (if `n` is a power of 2).

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking why the two loops have a different running time (the second being much slower), the reason is that most calls to `list.add(i, i)` don't need to re-create the backing array.

Only when the backing array becomes full, a larger array is created. And the larger array is 50% larger than the original array, so it can handle many subsequent calls to `add` before it becomes full.

Answer (score 0):

Because `grow()` is not always called when a new element is added. The `ArrayList` is always increased by a factor of 50%.

The relevant lines are those:

```
int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

The `(oldCapacity >> 1)` is doing a bit shift to the right, so dividing by 2. This means that `newCapacity` is +50% of `oldCapacity`. Only if this is exceeded, the next call to `grow()` is made.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.copyOf` is as slow as expected. Whileas `List.add()` is as quick as expected, since  `Arrays.copyOf` in the `grow` method doesn't occur every time the `add` method is called. `grow` only occurs when the capability of the `ArrayList` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is [amortized runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). Your implementation copies the entire array each time a new copy is created. Each copy-operation is `O(n)`, making the cost of the entire operation

```
1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2 = O(n^2)
```

`grow` on the other hand increases the size in a different manner. The new size of the array is calculated in this line:

```
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

which essentially boils down to

```
int newCapacity = (int) (oldCapacity * 1.5)
```

So once the array is filled up, the array grows by a factor of 1.5

This in comparison takes for `n` insertions and an initial size `m`

```
m + 1.5 * m + 1.5 ^ 2 * m + ... + n = 
m + 1.5 * m + 1.5 ^ 2 * m + ... + 1.5 ^ log_1.5(n / m) * m = 
m * (1 - 1.5 ^ (log_1.5(n / m) + 1) / (1 - 1.5) = 
m * 2 * (n / m * 1.5 - 1) =
3 * n - 2 * m
```

The amortized runtime can be calculated as the total cost for `n` insertions divided by `n`:

```
(3 * n - 2 * m) / n = 3 - 2 * m / n
```

Since `m < n` in your case the second part of the equation becomes negligible, and we we end up with `O(1)` as amortized runtime and a runtime for all insertions of `O(n)`, which significantly differs from the `O(n^2)` for copying the entire array after each insert.